# Return the names of data frames from a loop into a new data frame as IDs

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, rbind

Suppose I have multiple data frames with the same prefixes and same structure.

```
mydf_1 <- data.frame('fruit' = 'apples', 'n' = 2)
mydf_2 <- data.frame('fruit' = 'pears', 'n' = 0)
mydf_3 <- data.frame('fruit' = 'oranges', 'n' = 3)
```

I have a for-loop that grabs all the tables with this prefix, and appends those that match a certain condition.

```
res <- data.frame()

for(i in mget(apropos("^mydf_"), envir = .GlobalEnv)){
  
  if(sum(i$n) > 0){
    res <- rbind.data.frame(res, data.frame('name' = paste0(i[1]),
                                            'n' = sum(i$n)))
  }
}

res
```

This works fine, but I want my 'res' table to identify the name of the original data frame itself in the 'name' column, instead of the column name. **My desired result is**:

[image]

The closest I have gotten to solving this issue is:

```
'name' = paste0(substitute(i))
```

instead of

```
'name' = paste0(i[1])
```

but it just returns 'i'.

Any simple solution? Base preferred but not essential.

Comment: If a data.frame have many kinds of fruit, do you want to discard the fruit names and sum their counts together?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. @DarrenTsai

Comment: You should really be using lists. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451): Don't ever create `d1` `d2` `d3`, ..., `dn` in the first place. Create a list `d` with `n` elements.

Comment: And I'm still hoping for that `base` approach that should be, reasonably. achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is better to put dataframes into a list as it  much easier to handle and manipulate them. However, we could still grab the dataframes from the global environment, get the sum for each dataframe, then bind them together and add the dataframe name as a row.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list <-
  do.call("list", mget(grep("^mydf_", names(.GlobalEnv), value = TRUE))) %>%
  map(., ~ .x %>% summarise(n = sum(n))) %>%
  discard(~ .x == 0) %>% 
  bind_rows(., .id = "name")
```

Or we could use `map_dfr` to bind together and summarise, then filter out the 0 values:

```
map_dfr(mget(ls(pattern = "^mydf_")), ~ c(n = sum(.x$n)), .id = "name") %>%
  filter(n != 0)
```

**Output**

```
    name n
1 mydf_1 2
2 mydf_3 3
```

Comment: In this case `map_dfr` is more suitable than `map_df` becasue it has its own arg `.id` and runs `bind_rows` under the hood (so you don't need to call `bind_rows` again).

Comment: @DarrenTsai Good call! Thanks very much; that's much more concise and more efficient. Definitely still learning about the flexibility of the `map` family.

Answer (score 1):

To bind a list of data.frames and store the list names as a new column, a convenient way is to set the arg `.id` in `dplyr::bind_rows()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

mget(apropos("^mydf_")) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "name") %>%
  count(name, wt = n) %>%
  filter(n > 0)

#     name n
# 1 mydf_1 2
# 2 mydf_3 3
```